# How to write first order system of equations equivalent to certain ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to write down first order system of equations equivalent to the differential equation $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x^2\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2.$$

Comment: The first thing you can do is to introduce a new function: $$u(x)=dy/dx$$, because there are only derivatives in your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have the ODE :$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x^2\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2$which can be written as

\begin{align}
   y_1&=y'\\
  y_2&=y_1'\\
 y_2'&=y_2-x^2y_1^2
\end{align}